# ASP.Net C# - Using a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, session-variables, datareader

I hope this makes sense. I'm familiar with using DataReaders, however I think using a DataTable in this instance makes sense.  I have a database table that includes 'questions' and I want to implement a facility to be able to browse through the questions on a website.

So, simplified, there's a label to output the question (lblQuestion) and a back button and a forward button to go to the previous/next question.

Is the following code/saving the DataTable in a Session object the most efficient way to do this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(Page.IsPostBack))
    {
        getQuestions();
        int questionCounter = 1;
        ViewState["questionCounter"] = questionCounter;
        lblCounter.Text = questionCounter.ToString();
    }
}

protected void getQuestions()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE approved='Y' AND module_id=1";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
        Session["dt1"] = dt1;

        lblQuestion.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["question"].ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        lblError.Text = "Database connection error - failed to get questions.";
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}

protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int questionCounter = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["questionCounter"]);
    DataTable dt1 = (DataTable)Session["dt1"];

    if (questionCounter < dt1.Rows.Count)
    {
        questionCounter++;
        lblQuestion.Text = dt1.Rows[questionCounter-1]["question"].ToString();

        ViewState["questionCounter"] = questionCounter;
        lblCounter.Text = questionCounter.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        lblQuestion.Text = "the end of questions.";
    }
}

protected void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int questionCounter = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["questionCounter"]);
    DataTable dt1 = (DataTable)Session["dt1"];

    if (questionCounter > 1)
    {
        questionCounter--;
        lblQuestion.Text = dt1.Rows[questionCounter-1]["question"].ToString();

        ViewState["questionCounter"] = questionCounter;
        lblCounter.Text = questionCounter.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        lblQuestion.Text = "the beginning of questions.";
    }
}
```

Comment: How many questions are there now? How many will there be in a year? Will users always click for more questions? i.e. how often will all questions be looked at?

Comment: yes the code of the DataTable will store data in a Session object properly

Comment: @PaulZahra Ignoring the conditions in the SQL statement in the code shown, currently 20 questions. 100+ in a year. I don't quite understand your last question. All questions can't be viewed at once but I imagine users would click the 'next' button all the way to the end of the question 'bank' often.

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldn't really store data in the session object. The reason for this is that every user will have that datatable stored against them. That means if the table is 1MB and you have 100 users, then you will have 100MB of session objects. Obviously this is not very good.

Instead what you can do is use the Application Cache. This is different to the session store as it is shared across all users (and is cleared upon IIS Application Pool recycle). It's as easy as saving to the session object, but you just use the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) instead.

In your code you should check to see if the cache contains the questions table already. If it does then just return it, otherwise do your SQL query to populate it. If your questions tend to change regularly then consider using [expiration timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9.aspx) that will automatically remove the object after a period of time you define. Then the next time a user queries the question table, your code will detect that it has been removed and request it again.